# Which switches can I use for Ethernet bonding?

Tags: networking, bonding, switch

I'm just about to configure a DELL PowerEdge T410 server with 2 network cards. I'm trying to decide for a network switch and I'll need to configure the server for [link aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) later. I read the Wikipedia article and it mentions IEEE 802.3ad and IEEE 802.1AX standards. However I have some difficulty in understanding whether a cheap switch conforms to these standards, e.g. [D-Link DGS-2205 5-Port 10/100/1000 Desktop Switch](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=494). What kind of expression should I check in the descriptions of switches when I'm looking for a switch so that I won't have issues in terms of ethernet bonding later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one of seven "interface bonding modes" [read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation#Interface_Bonding_Modes) need that specific switch support.